# How to set system property using testng.xml and beanshell

Tags: beanshell, testng.xml

I have an XML configured like this

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="SuiteName" verbose="7">
    <test name="TestName">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                    <![CDATA[
                    driverType = System.getProperty("driverType");
                    if (driverType.equals("IOS")){
                      return groups.containsKey("All") && (!groups.containsKey("wip") && !groups.containsKey("iOS"));
                    } else {
                       return groups.containsKey("All") && (!groups.containsKey("wip"));
                    }
]]></script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="classnameHere"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Now I have a Jenkins job that sends a command -DsuiteXmlFile=${suiteXmlfile}.xml   (i have multiple suites XML files configured)

The tests create reports that contain in name the "suiteXmlFile" param value, but for debug or when I have to run something not form Jenkins I just right click on the XML file but the reporter see suiteXmlFile as empty (obviously).

I tried System.setProperty("suiteXmlFile","suiteName"); (i use this inside methods and works well) but from the XML file it seems it doesn't work. Is there any other way to set that property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.setProperty("suiteXmlFile","suiteName") actually works. the problem was that I was trying to read that property before it was set by xml